# Collection to hold maximum number of running Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need a collection/bag (something) that will hold some maximum number running `Task` objects. Adding a new running `Task` to the collection should block the calling thread (there are many threads trying to add a task so it should be thread safe) until there is an available slot for the new Task to be added if the maximum number of running tasks is reached. This is what I have so far and it is working fine.

```
public class ConcurrentTaskLimiter
{
    public int MaxWorkingTasks { get; }
    private readonly Task[] _tasks;
    private readonly bool[] _finished;

    public ConcurrentTaskLimiter(int maxWorkingTasks)
    {
        MaxWorkingTasks = maxWorkingTasks;
        if ((1 <= maxWorkingTasks) == false)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxWorkingTasks), maxWorkingTasks, "Must be >= 1");
        _tasks = new Task[maxWorkingTasks];
        _finished = new bool[maxWorkingTasks];

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxWorkingTasks; i++)
        {
            _tasks[i] = Task.FromResult(0); // use this as finished tasks
            _finished[i] = true;
        }
    }

    public void BlockAdd(Task t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));

        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled
            || t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted
            || t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            return;

        lock (this)
        {
            int i;
            while (true)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < MaxWorkingTasks; i++)
                {
                    if (_finished[i])
                    {
                        _tasks[i] = t;
                        _finished[i] = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                i = Task.WaitAny(_tasks);
                _finished[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you find any problem with this code? Or is there some built in class that can handle this kind of task :) ?

Comment: if your code works fine post this on codereview other wise tell what is the problem.

Comment: You should look in to [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx), it likely has what you need.

Answer (score 2):

.NET has a class called [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137(v=vs.110).aspx) that could greatly simplify the task for you.

Instances of blocking collection can be initialized with an upper limit on the number of tasks it can hold. When you do this, the call to `Add` will block when adding a task would cause the collection to exceed the capacity.

Comment: I thought of BlockingCollection<T>, but in this case how do I remove/drop the finished tasks to free room for the new running tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SynchronizedCollection<T>` it will take care of thread safety for you out of the box. Or use one of the many collections from `System.Collections.Concurrent`. I would use one from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` since they are much newer and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose more elegant solution.

```
    public class TasksPool
    {
        public int MaxSize { get; private set; }

        public TasksPool(int maxSize)
        {
            if (maxSize < 1) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Should be 1 or more");
            MaxSize = maxSize;
            _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxSize-1);
        }

        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

        public void Add(Task t, CancellationToken token)
        {
            _semaphore.Wait(token);

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            t.ContinueWith(q => _semaphore.Release(), token);
        }
    }
```